# Sharing props definition between components or create a Model

Tags: reactjs

I am creating some specific models between components and I thought about the two approaches, one having a specific model created with a class definicion, and the other based in sharing the propTypes definition of a component.

I created two sandboxes with a example of them, but cannot determine what could be most scalable when a component receives several props or deeper objects.

Example of sharing props definition between components using a proptypes definition:
https://codesandbox.io/s/n7p40xlo6j

```
// FirstComponent.js
export const propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.shape({
    username: PropTypes.string,
    email: PropTypes.string,
  }),
};
const FirstComp = ({ user }) => (
    <div>
        <h2>First component</h2>
        <span>Username: {user.username}</span>
        <span> - </span>
        <span>Email: {user.email}</span>
    </div>
);
FirstComp.propTypes = {
    ...propTypes,
};
export default FirstComp;

// SecondComponent.js
import { propTypes } from './FirstComponent';
const SecondComp = ({ user }) => (
    <div>
        <h2>Second component</h2>
        <span>Email: {user.email}</span>
        <span> + </span>
        <span>Username: {user.username}</span>
    </div>
);
SecondComp.propTypes = { ...propTypes };
export default SecondComp;

// index.js
import FirstComponent from './FirstComponent';
import SecondComponent from './SecondComponent';
const [user1, user2] = [
    { username: 'user1', email: 'user1@default' },
    new User('user2', 'user2@default'),
];
const App = () => (
    <div>
        <FirstComponent user={user1} />
        <SecondComponent user={user2} />
    </div>
);
```

Example of sharing props definition between components using a model:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jp08k5oqzw

```
// userModel.js
class User {
    constructor(username, email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
export default User;

// FirstComponent.js
import UserModel from './userModel.js';
const FirstComp = ({ user }) => (
    <div>
        <h2>First component</h2>
        <span>Username: {user.username}</span>
        <span> - </span>
        <span>Email: {user.email}</span>
    </div>
);
FirstComp.propTypes = {
    user: PropTypes.shape(UserModel),
};
export default FirstComp;

// SecondComponent.js
import UserModel from './userModel.js';
const SecondComp = ({ user }) => (
    <div>
        <h2>Second component</h2>
        <span>Email: {user.email}</span>
        <span> + </span>
        <span>Username: {user.username}</span>
    </div>
);
SecondComp.propTypes = {
    user: PropTypes.shape(UserModel),
};
export default SecondComp;

// index.js
import User from './userModel.js';
import FirstComponent from './FirstComponent.js';
import SecondComponent from './SecondComponent.js';
const [user1, user2] = [
    { username: 'user1', email: 'user1@default' },
    new User('user2', 'user2@default'),
];
const App = () => (
    <div>
        <FirstComponent user={user1} />
        <SecondComponent user={user2} />
    </div>
);
```

Comment: For clarity and documentation purposes, please remove the links and paste the code examples in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice experiment. I don't think there is one answer, as with most things, it depends on what you want out of the code and what you mean by "scalable"

The first option with a "plain object" will be good for cases where you want to be able to dinamically change or extend the proptypes using the shared definition as a default, i.e:

```
const propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.shape({
    username: PropTypes.string,
    email: PropTypes.string,
  }),
};

const FirstComp = ({ user }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>First component</h2>
    <span>Username: {user.username}</span>
    <span> - </span>
    <span>Email: {user.email}</span>
  </div>
);
FirstComp.propTypes = {
  ...propTypes,
};

const SecondComp = ({ user }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Second component</h2>
    <span>Email: {user.email}</span>
    <span> + </span>
    <span>Username: {user.username}</span>
  </div>
);
// Not a particularly good example, but it illustrates my point
SecondComp.propTypes = { ...propTypes, email: PropTypes.shape({something}) };
```

Which is an interesting choice, if you're building say a suite of similar components that treat some propTypes differently from the rest.

The second option is nicer for consistency across usages of the model, which in this particular case of a User model would be preferrable in my opinion. It's abstracted away from the components and React's API, which is good since this particular model doesn't need to know about UI logic, and you could later improve it by providing things like different serialization options for sending it through an HTTP request without worrying about inconsistencies in the shape of the object across multiple components, getting a sort of "type-safety"

Comment: I think like you and we will go the second way. Creating a model through classes is a good option for sharing between technologies. That way, I lose the type checking and we will only see that the instance is correct structurally, but that can be done using flow types, typescript or others.